# Xcode 8 Storyboard issues

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, swift3, xcode8

So I've seen a few of the questions related to layout issues, but this doesn't seem to be solved by choosing **Update Frames** on the right panel; nor does choose to Open with: Xcode 7.x.

We're doing some trait variation where sometimes the constraints exist on a screen size and sometimes they don't. And lots of stack views.

Here's what it looks like initially on the iPhone 6s screen size:

[image: iphone6s]

If I switch over to iPad:

[image]

And finally a look at the iPhone 6S Plus:

[image]

Has anyone else dealt with this? It seems to look fine on simulator. The only way it looks correct on the different screen sizes is to: switch to screen size > close Xcode > reopen Xcode

but if I switch to another one, it maintains the view size of the initial screen size.

Answer (score 1):

Select all the Scenes(View Controllers) in the Storyboard, show the Size inspector, change the Simulated Size to Freeform, then set Width Height = 600.

Then, those tons of warnings disappear.

[image]

**OR**

At the bottom "View As" section is there. Click on it and it will show different devices.  Select a device and this will resolve the issue.